# Use Promise inside a function that return new Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I know about anti-pattern that can be happened while using Promises in javascript.
This is my scenario.
I have a request function that return a Promise.
I want to use this inside another function and execute some code in `then` and then resolve it or reject it in some condition:

```
export const login = (req: IRegisterAuthReq): Promise<IUserTokenResponse> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AuthApi.login(req)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.success) {
          store.dispatch(setUserLoggedIn(true));
          resolve(response.data as IUserTokenResponse);
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      })
      .catch(reject)
      .finally(() => {
        store.dispatch(setAppLoading(false));
      });
  });
};
```

This is my code, I call **AuthApi.login** function and execute some code and then resolve value.

and then use it like this:

```
login(req)
  .then(authoredSuccessful)
  .catch(authoredUnSuccessful);
```

I want to know if this approach is anti-pattern or bad, and if it is how can I achieve this functionality in best way.

Comment: "*I want to know if this approach is anti-pattern*" [yes, it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). There is almost no reason to use the `Promise` constructor. It's only useful if you *don't* already have a promise. If you use `.then` already, it's a promise. You're just adding a promise around your promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it's prettier to just chain promise call :

```
export const login = (req: IRegisterAuthReq): Promise<IUserTokenResponse> => {
  return AuthApi.login(req)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.success) {
          store.dispatch(setUserLoggedIn(true));
          return response.data as IUserTokenResponse;
        }
        throw new Error("Auth error")
      })
      .finally(() => store.dispatch(setAppLoading(false)));
};
```

And using async :

```
export const login = async (req: IRegisterAuthReq): Promise<IUserTokenResponse> => {
  const response = await AuthApi.login(req);
  
  try {
    if (response.success) {
      store.dispatch(setUserLoggedIn(true));
      return response.data as IUserTokenResponse;
    }
  
    throw new Error("Auth error");
  } finally {
    store.dispatch(setAppLoading(false));
  }
};
```

Comment: Tnx, I will wait for other answers, If there is no better answer, I will accept yours :)

Comment: "*In my opinion*" - not just yours :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know if this approach is anti-pattern or bad, and if it is how can I achieve this functionality in best way.

**Yes, wrapping an existing promise with another manually created promise is an anti-pattern.**  You're unnecessarily creating an extra promise and besides adding unnecessary code, it's also very easy to make mistakes in error handling.  See [Promise anti-patterns](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html) for more info on promise anti-patterns.  This one is known as the "Construction Anti-Pattern".  There are a number of other promise-related anti-patterns [here](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/).

Instead, you should be returning the promise you already have and using return values or exceptions inside the `.then()` handler to control the final resolved value of the promise chain.

```
export const login = (req: IRegisterAuthReq): Promise < IUserTokenResponse > => {
    return AuthApi.login(req).then(response => {
        if (response.success) {
            store.dispatch(setUserLoggedIn(true));
            return response.data;
        } else {
            // make promise chain reject
            throw new Error("login not successful");
        }
    }).finally(() => {
        store.dispatch(setAppLoading(false));
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```js
login()
.then( () => {
  handleSuccess()
})
.then( () => {
  doAnyOtherPromise()
})
.catch( error => {
  // here error can be an error rejected by any previous promise
  console.log(error)
});
```

More info on how to you promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Author want's to know about better ways to implement login not how promise chaining works.